# How to change scope variable when push notification received

Tags: javascript, angularjs, push-notification, web-worker

I have a notification icon in my web app that shows the number of notifications. The front end of the application is made using angularjs.

The count for the icon is stored in a `$rootScope` variable. I want to increment the variable(or call a web service that returns count) when a push notification is received.

The serviceworker.js file does not have access to the scope variables in angularjs. How do I change the count variable's value from the serviceworker.

I thought of adding a change event listener on `localStorage` item.

On logging in, I will create a item.

`localStorage.setItem('notifCount', 0);`

When I receive a push notification, I will increment `notifCount` in `localStorage` in `serviceworker.js` and the change event will fire. I could add the `localStorage` change listener in one of controller files and call a web service or just increment the `$rootScope` variable.

But this would happen even when someone manually changes the localStorage in dev tools.

I want to know if I can do it this way(if it's the right way) or is there a better method. I don't feel like this is the right way.

Comment: Assuming you have the communication between Angular (client) and service worker, you should wrap the updating of the angular variable in $apply.  If you haven't gotten communication working, take a look at a number of service worker communication links from google (http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html#.XQeLIIhKiHs).

Comment: using locationStorage for this seems weird. You can e.g. register service worker listener in app.run and change $rootScope variable there.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov and you can't access the `localStorage` in serviceworker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is sent between workers and the main thread via a system of messages — both sides send their messages using the [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) method, and respond to messages via the `onmessage` event handler (the message is contained within the Message event's data attribute.) The data is copied rather than shared.

For more information, see

- [MDN Web API Reference - Using Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)